# How to detect 45 degree edges in an image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

If instead of getting all edges, I only want edges that make 45 degree angles.  What is a method to detect these?

Would it be possible to detect all edges, then somehow run a constrained hough transform to detect which edges form 45 degrees?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is wrong with using an diagonal structure element and simply convolve the image??

### Details

Please read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Formulation) and it should become clear how to build the structuring element. If you are familiar with convolution than you can build a simple structure matrix which amplifies diagonals without theory

```
{ 0,  1,  2}, 
{-1,  0,  1}, 
{-2, -1,  0}
```

The idea is: You want to amplify pixel in the image, where 45deg below it is something different than 45deg above it. Thats the case when you are at a 45deg edge.

Taking an example. Following picture

[image]

convolved by the above matrix gives a graylevel image where the highest pixel values have those lines which are exactly 45deg.

[image]

Now the approach is to simply binarize the image. Et voila

[image]

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate?

Comment: You didn't explain the reasoning behind why they use this particular matrix

Comment: @pooria The reasoning behind it that we use a simple [Sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) which are easy convolution kernels to detect horizontal and vertical edges. Now, just look at the matrix and try to rotate it by 45 degree. If you search for "sobel 45 degree", you should also find some hits.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is possible to do this as post processing. 
The result of Hough is in the parameter space of (angle,radius).
So you can simply take a slice in say angle=(45-5,45+5)  and all radiuses.

An alternative method is that the output of edge detection will contain only 45/135 angle edges.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a kernel but want line equations, then you'll still have to perform a line fit after the edge pixels are found. If you're certain the lines are exactly 45 degrees, then knowing the (x,y) point on any discovered line or line segment is sufficient to find the line equation.

Hough (rho, theta) parameter space can use whatever ranges of rho and theta that you'd like. You might preprocess the image to favor neighbor pixels at the proper angle. For example, give a "bonus point" to an edge pixel if it has 8-neighbors at the appropriate angle. You can certainly mix a kernel-based method (such as halirutan suggested) with a parametric or parameterless Hough algorithm.

A recent implementation of Hough runs at blazing fast speeds, so if you're looking for a quick solution you might download the open source code and then simply filter the output.

"Real-time line detection through an improved Hough transform voting scheme"
by Fernandes and Oliveira
http://www.ic.uff.br/~laffernandes/projects/kht/index.html